# detecting cofinality in ordinals

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

Suppose K is an unbounded well ordered set, and suppose K is minimal in the sense that each proper initial segment of K has strictly smaller cardinality.

Suppose J is an unbounded well ordered set of the same cardinality as K.

Must there exist a subset M of K, and an order preserving embedding f:M--->J so that f(M) is cofinal in J?

( i.e. for each j in J there exists m in M so that j is less than f(m)).

( In earlier versions of this question, if we overreach and demand that M=K, Brian and Asaf observed the answer is no, even if each final segment of J has the same cardinality as K)

Comment: Please don't change the question this much. You essentially rendered Brian's answer unfitting. The question you are asking is trivially true. It's easy to see that it is always the case that $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)\leq\alpha$; and without a lot of trouble one can show that $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)$ is always a cardinal. These two combined make the result obvious.

Comment: Thanks Asaf and Brian and I'm sorry for changing the question this much, I didn't realize the edits would destroy the earlier version. I don't see how build m

Answer (score 2):

No: the cardinal $\omega_1$, which as an ordinal is the least ordinal of its cardinality, cannot be embedded cofinally in $\omega_1+\omega$ by any order-preserving function, strict or not, and $\omega_1+\omega$ has the same cardinality as $\omega_1$.

**Added:** Suppose that $f:\omega_1\to\omega_1+\omega$ is (not necessarily strictly) order-preserving and cofinal. For each $k\in\omega$ there is an $\alpha_k\in\omega_1$ such that $f(\alpha_k)\ge\omega_1+k$. Let $\alpha=\sup\{\alpha_k:k\in\omega\}$; then $\alpha_k\le\alpha$ for each $k\in\omega$, so $\omega_1+k\le f(\alpha_k)\le f(\alpha)$ for each $k\in\omega$, and therefore $$f(\alpha)\ge\sup\{\omega_1+k:k\in\omega\}=\omega_1+\omega\;,$$ which is impossible, since $\omega_1+\omega\notin\omega_1+\omega$.

**Added<sub>2</sub>:** The answer to the revised version of the question is still *no*. For a counterexample let $K=\omega_1$, and let $J$ be the ordinal product $\omega_1\cdot\omega$. Pictorially $J$ is $\omega$ copies of $\omega_1$ strung end to end:

$$\overset{\omega_1}\longrightarrow\overset{\omega_1}\longrightarrow\overset{\omega_1}\longrightarrow\overset{\omega_1}\longrightarrow\dots$$

Each final segment of $J$ contains countably infinitely many copies of $\omega_1$, but the cofinality of $J$ is only $\omega$.

Comment: Brian, the requirement is that $K$ is unbounded. $\omega_1+1$ is bounded. Moreover there was a requirement that every proper initial segment has a strictly smaller cardinality by $\omega_1$ and $\omega_1+\omega$ have the same cardinality. So both examples are irrelevant to the question, but they do show the necessity of these conditions.

Comment: @Asaf: True; I temporarily forgot that when I scrolled the question out of sight. But $\omega_1+\omega$ works fine.

Comment: Yeah, you're right about the second one.

Comment: THanks Brian and Asaf! I hope you will see the new and improved question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. M is built by transfinite recursion as follows.

Fix a bijection h:K--->J.

Let m_1=1, the minimal element of K.

Suppose M_*={m_1 < m_2 ....} has been constructed and the restriction of h to M_* is order preserving.

1) Stop if the restriction has cofinal image and let M=M_*.

2) Otherwise obtain m_* > M_* minimal so that h(m_star) > h(M_star).

To check that the above construction is well defined and eventually terminates in the desired set M, suppose f(M_star) is not cofinal, obtain y>f(M_star), let h(x)=y, and note by construction x>M_star. If at some stage M_* is cofinal in K let M=M_*. The former sentence ensures 2) cannot happen.