# Reducing ordinals in the representation of a limit ordinal as $\bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} \beta$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Let $\alpha$ be a limit ordinal such that $\kappa$ < $\alpha$ < $\kappa^{+}$
where $\kappa$ is initial ordinal (so $|\alpha| = \kappa$).

I want to know whether or not I can find a sequence {$\beta_{i}$} where $ i < \kappa$ such that $\beta_{i} < \beta_{j} $ iff $i<j$, and $\bigcup_{i < \kappa} \beta_{i} = \alpha$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469241/detecting-cofinality-in-ordinals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily: you cannot do it if $\kappa>\omega$ and $\alpha=\kappa+\omega$. For regular $\kappa$, like $\omega_1$, you can do it if and only if the [cofinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinality#Cofinality_of_ordinals_and_other_well-ordered_sets) of $\alpha$ is $\kappa$.

Comment: what if I switch $\beta_{i} < \beta{j}$ by $\beta_{i} \leq  \beta{j}$

Comment: @GAJO: Assume for simplicity that $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal. Either there are $\kappa$ values of $i$ such that $\beta_i<\beta_{i+1}$, in which case $\bigcup_{i<\kappa}\beta_i$ has cofinality $\kappa$, just as if $\langle\beta_i:i<\kappa\rangle$ were strictly increasing, or $\langle\beta_i:i<\kappa\rangle$ is eventually constant, meaning that there is a $\gamma<\kappa$ such that $\beta_i=\alpha$ whenever $\gamma\le i<\kappa$. I doubt that that’s what you really want.

Comment: I want to find some sequence {$\beta_{i}$} with $i < \gamma <= \kappa$ 
such that $\bigcup_{i < \gamma} \beta_{i} = \alpha$.

Comment: @GAJO: For this you need to let $\gamma=\operatorname{cf}\alpha$, the cofinality of $\alpha$; see the link in my answer. If $\gamma=\operatorname{cf}\alpha$, then by definition there is a strictly increasing sequence $\langle\beta_\xi:\xi<\gamma\rangle$ such that $\bigcup_{\xi<\gamma}\beta_\xi=\alpha$.

Comment: Ok, thank you for answering

Comment: @GAJO: You’re welcome.

Comment: Why is it true if I assume regularity? ($\omega_{1}$ is regular and for $\alpha = \omega_{1} + \omega$ it is impossible to find such sequence like you said)